# Can DHCP requests leak information to my ISP while I am connected to a VPN?

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn, dhcp

I don't know a lot about networking, so this question might have some basic misconceptions.

I'm using OpenVPN 2.4.6 (server) and OpenVPN GUI 11.10.0.0 (client).

My server is configured with:

```
push "redirect-gateway def1"
```

Per the [OpenVPN man page](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/Openvpn24ManPage), the redirect-gateway option "[a]utomatically execute[s] routing commands to cause all outgoing IP traffic to be redirected over the VPN."

I worry that the following can happen.

1. My DHCP client sends out a DHCP discovery message. This message does not go through the VPN.
2. My ISP's DHCP server responds with an offer of an IP address.
3. My DHCP client requests the offered IP address and receives an acknowledgment. Again this request does not go through the VPN.
4. I connect to the VPN.
5. The lease on my non-VPN IP address expires.
6. My DHCP client requests to renew the lease. This request goes through the VPN.
7. My ISP can now associate my non-VPN IP address with my VPN IP address, based on information provided by my DHCP client in steps 1, 3, and 6.

dhcpcd, for instance, is said to include the MAC address of your network adapter in its requests. (See http://klamp.works/2016/04/29/dhcp.html.)

Is this a valid concern? If so, how can I address it?

I could be wrong, but it looks to me like one solution is to configure my VPN server with:

```
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
```

Per the [OpenVPN man page](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/Openvpn24ManPage), the bypass-dhcp flag "[a]dd[s] a direct route to the DHCP server (if it is non-local) which bypasses the tunnel (Available on Windows clients, may not be available on non-Windows clients)."

I'm using the redirect-gateway option because if I do not, when I connect to my VPN and browse to [dnsleaktest](https://www.dnsleaktest.com/), it shows my non-VPN IP address rather than my VPN IP address.

Thank you and please let me know if I can provide additional information.

Answer (score 1):

This concern us unfounded because DHCP applied only to a specific interface - and the VPN interface does not handle DHCP requests (I'm simplifying here - it may be able to handle DHCP requests but only across the tunnel when in TAP mode - but these font go go your ISP unencrypted, and similarly it will not here requests from your ISP.)

Where leakage can occur is if you use your ISPs nameservers (which can be assigned using DHCP) and these are on the same subnet as your  WAN Interface.